# Can I prevent a class from being inherited by a non-abstract object?

Tags: c#, inheritance

Consider the following classes:

```
public abstract class Planet
{
    protected abstract Material Composition { get; }
}

public abstract class TerrestrialPlanet : Planet
{
    protected override Material Composition
    {
        get
        {
            return Type.Rocky;
        }
    }
}
public abstract class GasGiant : Planet
{
    protected override Material Composition
    {
        get
        {
            return Type.Gaseous;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent a non-abstract object from inheriting directly from class `Planet`?

In other words, can we enforce that any class that directly inherits from `Planet` be abstract?

```
// ok, because it doesn't directly inherit from Planet
public class Earth : TerrestrialPlanet { ... }

// ok, because it is abstract
public abstract class IcyPlanet : Planet { ... }

// we want to prevent this
public class Pluto : Planet { ... }
```

Comment: What's the problem with a non-abstract class inheriting from the base?  Why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: No, that isn't possible the way you are asking.

Comment: Closest might be to change `Planet` to an interface `IPlanet` and use composition instead of inheritance to implement whatever 'planet' stuff you need in each of the planetary types. But that still wouldn't prevent someone from implementing a `Pluto` implementing `IPlanet`.

Comment: @DStanley - this whole thing is an allegory for two types of MVC controller that inherit from a base controller. They have similar public methods (`Index`, `Download`, etc...) that accept different parameters and then standardize them for use in the base class. I want to prevent someone from inheriting from the base class by accident, because then none of their MVC pages would work (since they would have no public methods, and it doesn't make sense in the context of the project).

Comment: @Chris Seems like that problem would be apparent very quickly.  There's not a compile-time way to prevent it, best you could do is inspect the inheritance tree at run-time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent a non-abstract class from inheriting a given public class that you create.

If all of the classes deriving from the base will be in the same assembly, and none of the concrete classes will, you could make the base class `internal`, to avoid exposing it externally *at all*, which would prevent other assemblies from extending it directly.  If it needs to be exposed publicly, or the concrete implementations will be in the same assembly, then this of course isn't an option.